# Killed: 9 error while running ssh on Mojave

Tags: macos, ssh, mojave

I am trying to connect via ssh to the remote GitHub server using Mac OS Mojave.

I generated the Key pair and when I execute the following command in bash:

ssh -T git@github.com

I get this error:

Killed: 9

I do not know how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: you can ask the program kill what it means `$ kill -l | column`

Comment: So your program receives a SIGKILL (probably by the OOM killer):

    SIGKILL

    Default action: Abnormal termination of the process.

    Description: Kill (cannot be caught or ignored).

Comment: Test your connection in Terminal `ssh -T git@github.com` observe

Comment: @David-carvajal Please describe what you did before entering the ssh command. It being killed with a signal 9 is not normal for that type of command. It indicates either that you have something running on your system that are closing these processes down automatically, that you're running out of resources - or that you did something "weird" with the previous commands given in the Terminal.